# Model completeness for rails 4

Tags: model, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am new to RoR, using Rails 4.0 and I need to to calculate how complete a model instance is. 
I have a user model with {first_name, last_name, email, description, location}. If you have any suggestions about similar gems (like completeness-fu) or any other way to do it will be very helpful.

Comment: It's been a long time.. I created a custom method to calculate the percentage. Not a good solution but it worked

Comment: That's what I'm currently working on now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced same issue few days ago. I solved this without any gem. I wrote a article on linkedin regarding the solution. You can check this link: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/calculating-completeness-attributes-rails-models-ravi-kashyap/

Or you can simply do this in you user model:

```html
def self.total_columns
  column_names.count 
end

def self.all_columns
  column_names 
end

def filled_columns
  counter = 0
  self.class.all_columns.each do |column|
    if self.attributes[column].present?
      counter += 1 
    end
  end
  counter
end

def completeness
  "#{(self.filled_columns * 100) / self.class.total_columns} %"
end
```

Hope this will help you but I also suggest you to go through this link because there I mentioned how you can reuse the code. 
Thanks